# Boot scripts on different distributions

Tags: python, ubuntu, boot

I've made a script to register and un-register a server:
    python registerTool.py start
    and
    python registerTool.py stop

I want to run these tools on boot and on shutdown. but is there a tool that can make scripts for me for different distributions like Ubuntu, Debian, Archlinux etc..

Is there a tool that can do this for me?

Comment: Ubuntu can probably use Debian boot scripts without to much trouble, other distributions will be more problematic. Just look at the existing scripts in `/etc/init.d/` to see how they work, and ask on the distribution forums.

Comment: Good question. There are none I've heard of. Most projects leave the init script up to the distro package managers.

Comment: You can use Linux shell scripting to accomplish this kind of a task.

Comment: Try http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home (sorry I don't know any details).

Comment: Chef is a good idea but i will use it later. http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2009/06/command-line-init-script-generator-for.html is a start

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux distributions support the SysV system for managing runlevel scripts.

You can use [update-rc.d](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=update-rc.d) to register scripts for the different runlevels. (see `man update-rc.d` on your systems for relevant docu).

For example: `update-rc.d <your-script> defaults`

This will make links to start the service in runlevels 2345 and to stop the service in runlevels 016 and will create the appropriate SysV-style scripts inside */etc/rc?.d/*

I am not sure if this will work directly with python scripts, but you can always wrap them in one-line-bash scripts.